# How can I Fix the CD/DVD refresh for the media drive so that it is recognized automatically?

Tags: 64-bit, cd, dvd, drive

I have recently installed Ubuntu 10.10 64bit and it seems to work flawlessly. But today I tried to check some CDs and I was surprised that Ubuntu doesn't automatically refresh the CD/DVDs inserted in my media drive.

I had to eject manually from the CD/DVD desktop icon >right click> Eject and then Insert the new CD and only then Ubuntu reads the data in the newly inserted CD/DVD.

**How can I fix the CD/DVD refresh for the media drive so that Ubuntu 10.10 recognize it automatically?**

Comment: Ubuntu should automatically recognise the CD/DVD media, if it doesn't then it's a real bug. Please report the bug by pressing Alt+F2 and typing in `ubuntu-bug ubuntu`

Comment: After typing the command I receive this message:  Package ubuntu does not exist :(

Comment: Sure enough, ubuntu doesn't exist as a package for ubuntu-bug.  Perhaps try ubuntu-desktop.  That should get a bug created if you think it's still not working the way it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretend that your CD/DVD drive does not have a manual ejection button.
Instead, r-click the Desktop icon and choose Eject.
There is also an Eject option in Nautilus when a CD/DVD has been mounted.
Or, from the command line type `eject`.
Or, [ALT]+[F2] `eject` and Run.

Unix-like systems "mount" a CD/DVD, incorporating the contents into the file system.
Not too-too long ago, the physical ejection button would not work at all
if a CD/DVD was currently mounted. By using the physical ejection button,
you have ejected the media, but Linux doesn't know about it, so it shows you what
it thinks is supposed to be there.

Comment: The key is to run `eject` _before_ mounting the new media. This also matters for VMs.